# expected type: java.lang.Double actual value: java.lang.Integer error in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

I call the stored procedure in hibernate using createSqlQuery interface and i am using result transformer for getting the result as bean.
below is my code for that

```
Query query=sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("exec usp_ListUsersNotSubmitTimesheet :startDate,:endDate");
        query.setDate("startDate", formatter.parse(startDate));
        query.setDate("endDate", formatter.parse(endDate));
        query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UnSubmittedTimesheetBean.class));
List queryList=query.list();
```

Some times sp result returns all integer values some times decimal values sometimes fixed.so i can't able to give the specific datatype.
so i  am getting the below exception

```
expected type: java.lang.Double actual value: java.lang.Integer
```

How to resolve this error?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I'd say you either have to create multiple stored procedures or use a single return type ( e.g. decimal ) and transform the `Double` value to `Integer` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your Stored Procedure is returning Integer data type value and I guess in your bean the mapped column is defined as Double so when Transformer is going to set the results in Bean it is trying to set Integer value to Double value and there it is throwing exception...

1> You can Either made changes in your Bean class (can make column as Integer).

2> you can change returned type of procedure that will return Double Precision.

3> and the complicated one of you are not allowed to change any of the above You can write your own Result Transformer by  Extending "AbstractQueryTransformer".

i prefer the second one.

Comment: can you add an example of implementation for option 2?

Comment: @C_B Find out which variable is the Bean complaining for. In my case I was returning a temportary table from the procedure with column Quantity INT(11). The bean in Java had private Float quantity (getters and setters). I changed the column in Stored Proc to Quantity FLOAT(4,2) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is just add casting in your stored procedure as what int / decimal

So that you can easily handle the datatype in your result transformer bean.
Otherwise in you result transformer make all those fields as "Number" and then change the "Number" object to any other things based on your need.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution,  change the stored procedure so that the result is always a double precision number, regardless of anything (you'll need to change the sp code, maybe the return type, as I don't know your sp).
Solution if you can't touch the db: Build a result transformer to accept integer, float, whatever and accomodate it into a double after doing some processing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar with complex SQL Joins for 2 fields. The exception shown on the console was

> expected type: java.lang.Double actual value: java.math.BigDecimal

To solve this I have explicitly mapped the datatype for those fields using addScalar() method

```
session.createSQLQuery(query.toString())
                .addScalar("offerid", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER)
                .addScalar("offervalue", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE)
```